# Option Strict appears to be considered as on despite being off since last Visual Studio Update

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, option-strict

Since last week's update of my Visual Studio all my projects are coming up with errors such as "*Option Strict On requires that all method parameters have an 'As' clause*" despite the project having the Option Strict "Off".

It's happening on all my projects.

The only way around I found is to go in Compile change the "Option Strict" to On, save the project, and change the "Option Strict" to Off and save the project again. This appears to solve the issue.

Anybody else with the same issue ?

[image: Print Screen of one project in Visual Studio]

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/160609/vb-option-strict-on-warnings-are-shown-on-existing.html

Comment: Have the same Problem. See article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775524/option-strict-appears-to-be-considered-as-on-despite-being-off-since-last-visual

Answer (score 0):

Fixed ! Found on developercommunity.visualstudio.com:

> Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed this issue and it's available in Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.5.2. Thank you for helping us build a better Visual Studio!
>   If you still see these error after upgrading to 15.5.2, please close Visual Studio and delete the .vs folder next to the solution file. This will clean up the IntelliSense cache that may be stale.